# Why does append convert timestamps in R?

Tags: r, timezone, append

I want to join a list of time zones into one long vector. Append seems to convert the time zones into the system time zone? Why?

```
> times = list(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01", tz = 'UTC', origin = "1970-01-01"),
+ as.POSIXct("2015-01-02", tz = 'UTC', origin = "1970-01-01"))
> times
[[1]]
[1] "2015-01-01 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2015-01-02 UTC"

> do.call(append, times)
[1] "2014-12-31 19:00:00 EST" "2015-01-01 19:00:00 EST"
```

I can't use unlist as it strips the list of the POSIXct class. What is the alternative?

Comment: Reason is documented e.g. in `?DateTimeClasses`: _"Using c on "POSIXlt" objects converts them to the current time zone, and on "POSIXct" objects drops any "tzone" attributes (even if they are all marked with the same time zone)."_.

Comment: So am I right in saying that append is a wrapper (or the other way) on c()? Also is there an alternative function that I could use here?

Comment: #1 Well look at the source: `getAnywhere(append)`. :) #2 Feel free to explore e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=r+c+posixct+timezone - not really, just resetting it?

Comment: #1 thanks - I didn't know such a function existed

Comment: You can also just type in the function name `append` to see the source. Concerning the time zone, maybe `lubridate::force_tz(do.call(c, times), "UTC")` - or you find a better solution as this is a common problem...

Comment: What about this: `as.POSIXct(unlist(times), tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01")`?

Comment: In all the above examples, you are circumventing the problem. First losing the timezone and the attaching it back. (even the google links say the same). Was wondering if there was a more straightforward solution as this feels ugly :).

Comment: I don't disagree that it's ugly. I just can't think of anything better.

Comment: @lukeA, using the lubridate code results in the underlying numeric value of the date being changed. Don't we want a method that maintains the same underlying numeric value of the date, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @eipi10 oops, I think I meant `with_tz` instead of `force_tz`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Hadn't used those functions before. Good to know.